# Matlab installed fine but won't start

Tags: matlab

I've installed the student version of Matlab 2013b, 64bit, in `/opt/matlab2013b`.

The installation wizard worked perfectly, I have the license and all, but when I navigate to

```
/opt/matlab2013b/bin
```

and run `./matlab`, nothing happens. (Weird though, it blocks the terminal and ^Z, ^C, ^D, nothing has any effect whatsoever).

Any idea how to try to debug this? I'd google it if there was any output but it just hangs right away, doesn't even make any kind of GUI.

(I have matlab 2012a installed elsewhere and it runs just fine)

ps system = Arch Linux 64bit.

Comment: Can you try `-nodesktop` switch to see what happens.

Comment: That's part of the issue, nothing happens :(

Comment: So the executable is starting but then locks up. This can be anything from a trivial problem to a bug that only the Matlab developers can fix. One thing that could help diagnose the issue is to run `strace -f -o matlab.strace ./matlab -nodesktop` and then post the trace (if it's extremely long, post at least the last 500 lines).

Comment: Nevermind, it starts when I'm on school wifi `eduroam' so it's likely just some nonsense with licenses. Still it's rather odd that it does not show any message and just hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the owner of `~/.matlab` from `root` to current user with `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer stolen from comments.

Matlab requires a license to run. For some installations, licenses can *checked out* from a license server. If MATLAB fails to contact the license server (e.g., because it is on a local intranet) MATLAB sometimes just hangs.